# MySQL with a LIKE returning wrong row

Tags: php, mysql, distinct, sql-like

I have the following:

```
 $q = "w0";

 $stmt = $db_found->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT callsign FROM NetLog WHERE callsign LIKE ?");
 $stmt->execute(array("%q%"));
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
 $print_r($result);
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [callsign] => KA0QIG
            [0] => KA0QIG
        )

)
```

So what went wrong? Why am I only getting one return when the DB has many values for callsign with 'w0'?

Comment: Please try `$stmt->execute(array("%$q%"));`. and check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `select distinct` with no wildcards.  So, you can only get at most one value.

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
$q = "%w0%";

$stmt = $db_found->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT callsign FROM NetLog WHERE callsign LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute($q);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$print_r($result);
```

Your version was just looking for the letter "q".

It occurs to me that you wanted:

```
$stmt->execute(array("%$q%"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is just the constant "%q%":

```
$stmt->execute(array("%q%"));
```

You need to interpolate the `$q` variable:

```
$stmt->execute(array("%$q%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My `$stmt->execute(array("%q%"));` has quotes instead of tick marks as in:

```
$stmt->execute(array('%q%'));
```

Which makes it work perfect.

Thanks.